# Ionic Capacitor Android build fails

Tags: android, react-native, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have a react ionic app that I am trying to convert to an Android app.
I did this for IOS without any problems, but when I am trying to Run the app on Android Studio it fails with this error:

```
yarin@h-MacBook-Pro-sl-Yarin-2 project % npx cap run android
✔ Copying web assets from build to android/app/src/main/assets/public in 21.14ms
✔ Creating capacitor.config.json in android/app/src/main/assets in 574.33μs
[info] Inlining sourcemaps
✔ copy android in 68.90ms
✔ Updating Android plugins in 4.05ms
[info] Found 5 Capacitor plugins for android:
       @capacitor/app@4.1.1
       @capacitor/device@4.1.0
       @capacitor/haptics@4.1.0
       @capacitor/keyboard@4.1.1
       @capacitor/status-bar@4.1.1
✔ update android in 32.75ms
✔ Please choose a target device: › Google sdk_gphone64_arm64 (emulator-5554)
✖ Running Gradle build - failed!
[error] 
        > Configure project :app
        WARNING:Using flatDir should be avoided because it doesn't support any meta-data formats.
        
        > Configure project :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins
        WARNING:Using flatDir should be avoided because it doesn't support any meta-data formats.
        
        > Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
        > Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
        > Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
        > Task :capacitor-android:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
        > Task :capacitor-android:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
        > Task :capacitor-android:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
        > Task :capacitor-app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
        > Task :capacitor-app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
        > Task :capacitor-app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
        > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
        > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
        > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
        > Task :capacitor-device:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
        > Task :capacitor-device:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
        > Task :capacitor-device:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
        > Task :capacitor-haptics:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
        > Task :capacitor-haptics:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
        > Task :capacitor-haptics:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
        > Task :capacitor-keyboard:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
        > Task :capacitor-keyboard:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
        > Task :capacitor-keyboard:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
        > Task :capacitor-status-bar:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
        > Task :capacitor-status-bar:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
        > Task :capacitor-status-bar:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
        > Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
        > Task :capacitor-android:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
        > Task :capacitor-app:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
        > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
        > Task :capacitor-device:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
        > Task :capacitor-haptics:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
        > Task :capacitor-keyboard:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
        > Task :capacitor-status-bar:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
        > Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
        > Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
        > Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug
        > Task :capacitor-android:writeDebugAarMetadata FAILED
        
        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
        
        * What went wrong:
        Execution failed for task ':capacitor-android:writeDebugAarMetadata'.
        > Failed to create parent directory
        '/Users/yarin/Desktop/dashboard/project/node_modules/@capacitor/android/capacitor/build' when creating directory
        '/Users/yarin/Desktop/dashboard/project/node_modules/@capacitor/android/capacitor/build/intermediates/aar_metadata/debug'
```

I would be really happy if someone can help me solve this issue.
No matter what I did it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Check your plugins, one of them is still using deprecated code "flatDir()". You may need to update one or many of them. You can use `npm outdate` and see which packages need upgrading.